Connecting snmp-exporter prometheus to cisco switches
I have a question about snmp exporter Prometheus, my problem is with this configuration
version: '3'

networks:
  monitoring:
    external: true

volumes:
  prometheus-data:

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.listen-address=:9091'

    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host

  snmp-exporter:
    image: prom/snmp-exporter
    container_name: snmp-exporter
    command:
     - '--config.expand-environment-variables'
    volumes:
      - ./snmp.yml:/etc/snmp_exporter/snmp.yml
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host

here is my prometheus.yml
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["172.31.0.148:9091"]

  - job_name: snmp
    metrics_path: /snmp
    params:
      module: [if_mib]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 172.31.0.40:161
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 127.0.0.1:9116

  - job_name: 'snmp_exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9116']

I get this error
server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request
I added this item in snmp.yml
head snmp.yml
# WARNING: This file was auto-generated using snmp_exporter generator, manual changes will be lost.
auths:
  public_v2:
    community: sasan
    version: 2
modules:
  apcups:
    walk:
    - 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.12
    - 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.2
...

The destination is a Cisco switch, and the snmpwalk machine is OK, and also snmp for Zabex is working at the same time, from this machine to the destination I said.
source: 172.31.0.148
destination: 172.31.0.40
I don't have any network or firewall problems.

Error 400 is commonly caused by using a module name in prometheus.yml that isn't defined in snmp.yml.
Check the module name in snmp.yml for what you want prometheus to scrape, and update prometheus.yml to use the correct module name.
You currently have prometheus.yml saying to monitor using module "if_mib". Can't see your full snmp.yml, but what I do see shows that you have a module named "apcups" defined. You just have to copy the correct module name that you defined for your Cisco stuff out of your snmp.yml and replace "if_mib" in your prmetheus.yml file with that value, and then restart prometheus.
